# How to obtain the p-values for each coefficient in a nested logit glmer model (using lme4)?

Tags: r, nested, logistic-regression, lme4

I'm running the following code:

```
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
nest.reg2 <- glmer(SS ~  (bd|cond), family = "binomial", 
    data = combined2)
coef(nest.reg2)
summary(nest.reg2)
```

Which produces the following output:

- coefficients

```
$cond    
          bd (Intercept)
LL -1.014698    1.286768   
no -3.053920    4.486349
SS -5.300883    8.011879
```

- summary

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: SS ~ (bd | cond)
   Data: combined2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1419.7   1439.7   -705.8   1411.7     1084 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.0524 -0.8679 -0.4508  1.0735  2.2756 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 cond   (Intercept) 33.34    5.774         
        bd          13.54    3.680    -1.00
Number of obs: 1088, groups:  cond, 3

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.3053     0.1312  -2.327     0.02 *
```

My question is how do I test the significance of each of the coefficients for this model? The Summary function seems to only provide a p-value for the intercept, not the coefficients.

When I try `anova(nest.reg2)` I get nothing, just:

```
Analysis of Variance Table
     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
```

I've tried the solutions proposed here (How to obtain the p-value (check significance) of an effect in a lme4 mixed model?) to no avail.

To clarify, the `cond` variable is a factor with three levels (`SS`, `no`, and `LL`), and I believe that the `coef` command produces coefficients for the continuous `bd` variable at each of those levels, so what I'm trying to do is test the significance of those coefficients.

Comment: see the answer to the question here from the maintainer of the package: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118416/getting-p-value-with-mixed-effect-with-lme4-package

Comment: Thank you! I've tried each of the "P" approaches outlined there, and have been unable to get p-values for each coefficient - only for the intercept. Are you aware of any other package that can accomplish this?

Comment: The model comparison approaches on that page aren't relevant (I don't think) because I'm not comparing 2 models, and the car::anova and lmerTest::anova approaches don't return any output for me. 

afex::mixed gives the following error: "Error in UseMethod("logLik") : no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "NULL""

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here.

- the main one is that you can really only do significance testing on *fixed effect* coefficients; you have coded your model with no fixed effects.  You might be looking for

```
glmer(SS ~ bd + (1|cond), ...)
```

which will model the overall (population-level) distinctions among the levels of `bd` and include variation in the intercept among levels of `cond`.

- If you have multiple levels of `bd` represented in each `cond` group, then you can *in principle* also allow for variation in treatment effects among `cond` groups:

```
glmer(SS ~ bd + (bd|cond), ...)
```

- *however*, you have another problem. Three groups (i.e., levels of `cond`) isn't really enough, in practice, to estimate variability among groups. That's why you're seeing a correlation of -1.00 in your output, which indicates you have a singular fit (e.g. see [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#zero-variance) for more discussion).
- therefore, another possibility would be to just go ahead and treat `cond` as a fixed effect (adjusting the contrasts on `cond` so that the main effect of `bd` is estimated as the average across groups rather than the effect in the baseline level of `cond`).

```
glm(SS~bd*cond,contrasts=list(cond=contr.sum),...)
```