# how to get the P-values in linear mixed model in R

Tags: r

I have 2 groups of `myope` and `non-myope` (34 participants) to measure the contrast sensitivity (CS) in 4 different cells over a time period.

I want to compare CS in different cells in 2 groups over that time.

Now my question is: how should I write my command to have 3 P-values for `Time`, `Cell` and `group`? I used this method, but i didn't give me any P-values:

```
NNtset1 = read.csv(file.choose())
LMM_alldata = lm(CS~Time+Class+(1|Groups),data=NNtset1,REML=FALSE)
summary(LMM_alldata)
```

Comment: The authors of the package left out the p-values due to the difficulty of determining the right number of degrees of freedom to use when evaluating the t-values. See this comment by the lme4 package creator: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain the p-values for each coefficient in a nested logit glmer model (using lme4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402087/how-to-obtain-the-p-values-for-each-coefficient-in-a-nested-logit-glmer-model-u)

Comment: Also, an informative discussion on the topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38188/cant-find-p-values-in-the-output-from-lmer-in-the-lm4-package-in-r

Answer (score 2):

Run the same code, but with `lmerTest` package attached and `lmer` function instead of `lm`, like this:

```
library(lmerTest)
LMM_alldata = lmer(CS~Time+Class+(1|Groups),data=NNtset1,REML=FALSE)
summary(LMM_alldata)
```